# How to get the most frequent non-empty value in a column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+
|   id|         name|    type|                 url|
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+
|    1|      NT Note|    aaaa|                null|
|    1|      NT Note|    aaaa|http://www.teleab...|
|    1|      NT Note|    aaaa|http://www.teleab...|
|    1|      NT Note|    aaaa|                null|
|    1|      NT Note|    aaaa|                null|
|    2|          ABC|    bbbb|                null|
|    2|          ABC|    bbbb|                null|
|    2|          ABC|    bbbb|                null|
|    2|          ABC|    bbbb|                null|
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+
```

I am assigning the most frequent `url` and `type` values to each node:

```
def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id", "url", "type") 
val result = df.withColumn("count", count("url").over(windowSpec))  
  .orderBy($"count".desc)                                                                                 
  .groupBy("id")                                                                                     
  .agg(
  first("url").as("URL"),
  first("type").as("Typel")
)
```

But in fact I need to **prioritize the most frequent non-null** `url` in order to get the following result:

```
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+
|   id|         name|    type|                 url|
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+
|    1|      NT Note|    aaaa|http://www.teleab...|
|    2|          ABC|    bbbb|                null|
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+
```

Now I get the below-shown output, because `null` is more frequent for the record id `1`:

```
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+
|   id|         name|    type|                 url|
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+
|    1|      NT Note|    aaaa|                null|
|    2|          ABC|    bbbb|                null|
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+
```

Comment: `first` has a second optional parameter called `ignore nulls`. You can set it to true and see if you get the required result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `udf` like below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

//function to return most frequent url

def mfnURL(arr: WrappedArray[String]): String = {
        val filterArr = arr.filterNot(_ == null)
        if (filterArr.length == 0)
            return null
        else {
            filterArr.groupBy(identity).maxBy(_._2.size)._1
        }
    }

//registering udf mfnURL

val mfnURLUDF = udf(mfnURL _)

//applying groupby , agg and udf

df.groupBy("id", "name", "type").agg(mfnURLUDF(collect_list("url")).alias("url")).show

//Sample output

+---+-------+----+--------------------+
| id|   name|type|                 url|
+---+-------+----+--------------------+
|  2|    ABC|bbbb|                null|
|  1|NT Note|aaaa|http://www.teleab...|
+---+-------+----+--------------------+
```

Comment: I get Tas Not Serializable error when I run it in the cluster deploy mode. It only works from spark shell.

Comment: You have to extend Serializable.

Comment: I did it. This code is located inside `class MyClass extends Serializable`. I also did `spark.udf.register("mfnURLUDF",mfnURLUDF)`. Nothing worked. I think that it is related to `filterArr`.

Comment: You have to also extend Serializable in class where this function is called from and where the spark.read() or spark.sql() function written.

Comment: I serialized everything I could. Now it points to the class `OrientGraph` which is external (from Jar). I cannot add `extends Serializable` to this class. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: UDF requires Serialization / Deserialization so we can avoid UDF , for that we have to implement filterArr.groupBy(identity).maxBy(_._2.size)._1 different way. Let me think another approach without udf

Comment: Thanks, it would be great to avoid UDF.